# Set JGrowl to be fixed on an iframe Joomla! page

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, joomla3.0, jgrowl

I've got a Joomla! iframe page, this page generate a JGrowl popup on a certain case. 
I tried a lot of thing to get this JGrowl to be fixed on screen but all of those didn't work. The popup always appear on top-right corner of the iframe, as i demanded, but doesn't stay fixed as i scroll.
However when i directly go to the source of the iframe, it works and the popup stay fixed on screen ignoring the scrolling.

I already tried the solution from this post : [iframe jQuery reference problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686166/iframe-jquery-reference-problem?rq=1)
Doesn't work.

Available for more informations.